# What's the use for a tapered handle socket wrench?

Tags: tools

When browsing around for tools I don't need I saw this socket wrench with a tapered handle.  What is this used for, and what makes the tapered handle more useful than a non-tapered/knurled handle?

[image: Photograph of a wrench with a tapered handle]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a tool for scaffolders or similar so they carry one tool and not two, given where they work having to keep changing tools means the risk of dropping one increases...

The taper is used to align the holes so the bolts go in.

Answer (score 1):

Similar (In the UK, a wrench is a spanner)

[image]

[image]